# Как проверить нажата ли клавиша в данный момент без задержки программы?

Tags: python

Знаю, что есть много вопросов на эту тему (не только на python), но я не нашел ответа решающего мою проблему.

Comment: `pip install keyboard`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать модуль `keyboard` с методом `is_pressed` вот так:

```py
import keyboard
while True:
    print(keyboard.is_pressed('esc'))
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне это помогло.